# NET Core strongly-typed data sources and designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, dataset, ado

I'm trying to port a NET Framework 4.7.2 app to NET Core 3.1 or 5.0 (doesn't matter to me). The app uses a Microsoft Access database (connected in the Server Explorer window of VStudio). It also uses a Data Source (visible in the VS Data Source window) to generate a strongly-typed dataset xxx.XSD (and associated files) to make it easy to work with the dataset in my program.

I load the dataset into memory and then do most of the work in the dataset (using LINQ, for example). I also use the dataset DataAdapters to write changes back to the database.

In my NET Core project (I tried both Core 3.1 and 5.0), I can connect to the database in VS okay to see all my tables, but VS says that the Data Source window is not available for my project.

All my code is written to use them, so it would probably be a big hassle to rewrite everything. I read somewhere here on SO that Datasets, Datatables, etc. were legacy technology that shouldn't be used these days. But they make my code easy and I don't have to learn yet another layer of technology to use them.

In the end, my app will run on Windows machines with a WinForms interface so NET Framework works fine at the moment, but if I can achieve the same on NET Core, I'd rather switch to NET Core sooner than later.

Is there an easy way to create strongly-typed datasets in NET Core with VStudio? Am I totally on the wrong track with using Datasets these days? Thank you.

For reference, [a Microsoft blog post here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/dot-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/) said that (in September 2019) "That’s why we don’t recommend porting your Windows Forms applications to .NET Core yet if you need to use the designer on a regular basis (the Forms designer, not the Data Source designer)."

Comment: "the Data Source window is not available" Are you referring to "this window is not supported for the selected project"? Yes, it seems not work fine in .NET Core and .NET5. Try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, that is the message that I am referring to. Maybe they have decided not to support it. I will post over there as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kyle Wang's comment above, I searched on the Developer Community website and found an answer as of May 2020:

> Thank you for sharing your feedback. This error is caused by the Datasource window doesn’t currently work with .NET Core projects. If you need to use the Datasource, please select the .NET Framework project.

This makes it easier to abandon my port to NET Core from my NET Framework projects!